# Plugin jquery cycle align images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-cycle

When use jquery plugin for rotate images , i see my images no show in center of div , the animation of jquery cycle move the images always to the left side , i try many things but never works and show in natural positions the images

**My code it´s next :**

```
<style>

#web_header_ani_ele_content
{
top:-130px;
position:relative;
width:360px;
height:175px;
border:1px solid;   
margin-left:340px;

#web_header_ani_texto
{
position:relative;
width:360px;
height:35px;
border:1px solid;
text-align:center !important;
bottom:-120px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>



<div id="web_header_ani_ele_content">
<div id="web_header_ani_texto">
<img src="imagenes/web/header/text_1.png" width="281" height="35" border="1"/>
<img src="imagenes/web/header/text_2.png" width="281" height="35" />
<img src="imagenes/web/header/text_3.png" width="281" height="35" />
</div>
</div>


<script>
jQuery('#web_header_ani_texto').cycle({ 
fx:'fade', 
speed:<?php echo $adm[banner_f_speed];?>, 
timeout:<?php echo $adm[banner_f_delay];?>, 
containerResize: 0,
nowrap: 0,
pause:1 
});
</script>
```

Thank´s the best regards for the help

Comment: put the images inside `<div>` and use css to align them within `<div>`

Comment: The images its inside div , you can see in the code

Comment: wrap each image in it's own `<div>` . The wrapped `<div>` will then be the slide. Cycle positions slide elements absolute but when img is inside you can set css for it

Comment: Can you put example of code , thank´s

Comment: read the FAQ on cycle site

Comment: I read andi can´t see nothing about this